# Exhaust Fan Code Requirements for Bathroom

Tags: electrical, bathroom

I have a small Full bathroom ( toilet, Tub and vanity) of size 6'X 7'.8". This is in a basement. We are hardly going to use tub/shower there.

Question:

1. Does a 50 CFM of Exhaust fan enough or does it has to be higher because I have full bathroom ?

Have this one and I know its a louder. I am ok with the noise.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-NuTone-50-CFM-Wall-Ceiling-Mount-Bathroom-Exhaust-Fan-696N/100081599

2. Does this fan has to be GFCI protected even if it is not directly above tub, although its 1 feet away from edge ( not wall side) of tub  ?

Right now, Only outlet is GFCI protected and, vanity lighting/Fan are on a different lighting 15 amp circuit.

Thanks for your help in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

After talking to Manufacture company , Answering to my own questions

Question : Does a 50 CFM of Exhaust fan enough or does it has to be higher because I have full bathroom ?
Answer : No. its based on just size of a bathroom.

Question : Does this fan has to be GFCI protected even if it is not directly above tub, although its 1 feet away from edge ( not wall side) of tub ?

Answer : If a fan is inside area of Shower/Bathtub. then GFCI protected needed. Let say if its just 6 inch outside of curtain road or Shower glass, the manufacture company doesn't require it as GFCI protected.

So it depends upon what type of fan do you have in your bathroom. you want to first check with manufacture company if you have the similar case.

Answer (score 2):

General rule of thumb is 1cfm per square ft. Should be fine in your case. The fan doesn't have to be gfci unless specified with the manufacturer but code doesn't make you.